# Iphone Application does not ask for permission everytime

Tags: ios, iphone, permissions, calendar, cllocationmanager

I have an ios app which uses calendar, location bluetooth and motion API. When i do a clean install to the app (remove the app completely from iPhone) and then build it using xCode, my app doesn't every time prompt to the user the consent dialog for example. **This app wants to use Calendar. Do you allow it to do that.**

I want to do some testing and i want this to prompt every time when user install the app after removing it from iPhone.

Any ideas?

Comment: is this happening in iPhone simulator, iPhone, or both??

Comment: i am using the Iphone Device not the simulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I know… the system alert is prompted to the user only once!

If you delete the application from your device, the privacy settings will not be removed and will be there even if you reinstall the application. To remove them you have to manually reset the privacy settings from General-> Reset-> Reset Location & Privacy.

Comment: Yes i figured it out thanks anyways or we can also change the bundle identifier of the app to get prompts.

Comment: Yes, changing the bundle id... "is like" a new app in town :)